# jquery get method working in safari but not in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, cross-browser

I have these two pages:

Page 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Test jquery.get()</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="result"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $.get('tests.html', function(data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
        alert(data);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Page 2:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="#" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <input type="text" name="some_name" value="" id="some_name">
        <p><input type="submit" value="Continue &rarr;"></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The first page loads the second page but it only works in Safari not in Firefox. What am I missing?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "works", can you clarify what you are getting?

Comment: What errors do you see in Firefox? Have you tried debugging with the built-in dev tools or Firebug?

Comment: Did you mean `alert(data);` I'm sure that's not your problem..just checking.

Comment: I don't see the div populated or the the alert box.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code is apparently injecting the markup of a whole HTML document into a `<div>` element. Firefox may not be happy with an `<html>` tree residing under a `<div>`.

Try reducing the markup to your `<form>` element in your call to `html()`:

```
$.get("tests.html", function(data) {
    $(".result").html($(data).find("form").html());
});
```

Or better, use [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/), which was designed for this purpose:

```
$(".result").load("tests.html form");
```

Comment: Then I'm afraid the problem lies elsewhere, so I second @j08691's suggestion: open a Firebug console and check what is reported there.